# TFS query type tree of workitems returns either root items or descendants, but never both in TFS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-2015

I knew the following worked in TFS 2012, but it's not working as expected (by me) in TFS2015 any longer. Bug or feature?
The screenshots I added are done VS2015, but I get the same results when using the TFS web pages.

Background:
We do have a set of work items which extend the standard work item set, their linkage is "Affects" / "Affected By":
[ "Domain Model" --> "Risk" --> "Mitigation" --> "Unit Test" --> "Task" ]
(where sub trees [Mitigation --> Unit Test --> Task] are optional, i.e. not always present, based on a risk value set in the "Risk" work items).

I'd like to set up a query to answer "Show all Domain Models with complete tree of workitems to detect missing (sub)items".
Therefore I start with Domain Models (for a given "Area Path"), and use "tree of work items" as query type.

Neither using "Match top-level work items first" nor "Match linked wi's first" as Linking Filter option ever shows a tree (i.e. with collapsable children / parent relations).
I either get all descendants shown, but without relations or the top level root items without relations ?!?
[Tree, linked items first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUwyB.png)

[Tree, top level first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjAv7.png)

Side note: when instead using query type "Work Items and Direct Links" it works as expected, i.e. showing me a 2-tier hierarchy of "Domain Model" to "Risk".

Any explanation greatly appreciated... ;-)

Comment: Tree always uses the parent/child relationship.

Comment: So it's a matter of the relationship. i.e. if we use parent/child instead of affects / affected by it would work?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yups. Just remember that while affects can be m:n, parent child is 1:n. You can configure a relationship to never become cyclic, but that doesn't turn it into a tree.